How can I replace a string in a field/column for all records using regex
I'm using MySQL 5.7 on a shared hosting server. There are plans to upgrade the MySQL, but until then, I'm on version 5.7.
I have a column in a table for phone_number varchar(20) .  For a business-reason I need to make the numbers be digits only. I need to strip out all non-numeric characters user have entered. I've tried a few tips found in forums, but none are working. Most do not work with MySQL 5.7.
For testing, I created a test table:
table: test_table
column: phone varchar(20) 

(example records)
-------------
(123) 444-5555
123.444.5555
123-444-5555

SQL:
update test_table set phone = replace(phone,'[^0-9]','');   -- anything not a number

This is one that does not error, but it does not update my column either.  How can I add a regex to this to make it work?  Or is there a better way?  Note: MySQL 5.7
I'm testing this SQL in a query-window in phpMyAdmin and in DbViz on my local machine.

REPLACE() doesn't use regular expressions, you need REGEXP_REPLACE(), which is in 8.0.
